# ios 9 play mp4 fullscreen video over HDMI lightning adapter

Tags: ios, video, mp4, airplay, hdmi

I'm, developing an iOS 9 app which works like a video kiosk. Users can tap on an iPad and a video should be displayed on a connected 1080p screen.

I've tried this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621293/how-to-output-video-on-external-display-with-controls-on-ipad) but it looks pretty outdated and isn't working any more.

From the Apple Developer Documentation, the AVPlayer looks like the right library to use. In former projects I've used MPMoviePlayer but this API seems to be deprecated in iOS9.

Is the AVPlayer the right way to go and do I need to handle the external display specifically or is this handled by iOS / Airplay.

Thank you in advance 
chris

Answer (score 1):

`AVPlayer` is the hard way to do that, because you should take into account a lot of aspects (about playback, load of resources, etc) that by using the common `MPMoviewPlayerController` or if you target >= iOS8 [AVPlayerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/) you have for free.
I do remember that MPMoviePlayerController handles Airplay by displaying the icon on the command bar or notification center, but if you can't "AirPlay" I think that you should handle by yourself the display of the player on another `UIWindow`. Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/UsingExternalDisplay/UsingExternalDisplay.html).

With the cable connector you can mirror it but you must compensate the black bar with specific [setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109542/ios-mirroring-mpmovieplayercontroller-to-tv-with-tv-screen-playback-in-fullscree).